# windows boot issue after hardware change

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd

so my current windows installation kicked the bucket, it was sightly curropted, a year of use later, i tried to fix it, and it went full corrupt. Anyway I have a second computer with amd apu. I put it's ssd in my current computer that is a 4930k. It boots in safe mode, but when I try to boot normally, it says "starting windows" forever. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1) put SSD back in your "second" computer

2) make backup of complete SSD

3) generalize SSD (generalize puts OS in state OOBE(out of box experience)

4) put SSD in "main" computer - it should boot after adapting to hardware

(you can restore later from backup to original state of SSD)

Answer (score 0):

The probable culprits are drivers for hardware that you don't have in the other computer.

The easiest way, since you have the "donor machine" around, is to put back the SSD and uninstall all chipset-, graphics, etc drivers and shutdown the computer and try again with just Microsoft's generic versions installed.

There are some ways to uninstall drivers and software in safe mode; for example you can get rid of display drivers with Display Driver Uninstaller ( http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html ).